# HTML Div takes up space while hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I made the following tabbedPage, but the hidden content still takes up space. Here is the code:

```js
let tabHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-header")[0];
let tabIndicator = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-indicator")[0];
let tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-content")[0];

let tabsPane = tabHeader.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (let i = 0; i < tabsPane.length; i++) {
  tabsPane[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    tabHeader.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabsPane[i].classList.add("active");
    tabContent.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabContent.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.add("active");

    tabIndicator.style.left = `calc(calc(100% / 2) * ${i})`;
  });
}
```

```css
/*--------------General----------------*/

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*-------------------------------------*/


/*-------------TabbedPage---------------*/

.tabbedpage {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div {
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div>i {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div.active {
  color: #d81e05;
  display: block;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-indicator {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: 5px;
  background: #d81e05;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0ms, transform 500ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div.active {
  opacity: 1;
}


/*--------------------------------------*/


/*---------------Footer-----------------*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
}

footer .red-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #d81e05;
  height: 120px;
}

footer .red-bar .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}


/*------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabbedpage">
    <div class="tabbedpage-header">
      <div class="active">
        statistics
      </div>
      <div>
        user management
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabbedpage-indicator"></div>
    <div class="tabbedpage-content">
      <div class="active">
        <h2>This is statistics section</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error neque saepe commodi blanditiis fugiat nisi aliquam ratione porro quibusdam in, eveniet accusantium cumque. Dolore officia reprehenderit perferendis quod libero omnis.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>This is the user management section</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi minus exercitationem vero, id autem fugit assumenda a molestiae numquam at, quisquam cumque. Labore eligendi perspiciatis quia incidunt quaerat ut ducimus?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="red-bar">
    <div class="container content">
      <p> Bel nu ons contact center <br> <b>023 751 06 06</b> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Now the TabbedPage is working the way I want, except that the content of a tab always uses space while not being showed. I can fix it by setting `position: absolute;`, but then the content goes trough the footer, which is also not allowed. So how can I remove the space that a hidden tab uses, while not going trough the footer?

Comment: You could give the tabbed page a height. It looks like you're trying to do that, but I don't think it's working. Might be better to use 100vh rather than 100%? Alternatively, you could fix the footer to the bottom of the page using `position:fixed`.

Comment: That doesn't work. I removed the height from Tabbedpage-content, but also no luck! Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: It should work, you have to get the implementation right. The issue is that your content is absolutely positioned so isn't pushing the footer down as it would if it was statically positioned. However, if it was statically positioned, it wouldn't animate properly.

Comment: If I do that, the 2 divs still take up the space, while they are hidden. How can I fix that then?

Comment: You could set a fixed height for the container of the tabs, e,g 500px, so that the content is always that high, but have `overflow-y:scroll` set on it so any content too large would be accessible through scrolling.  Alternatively, you could dynamically set the height of the container according to the content, but that would mean the footer 'jumping' between transitions. You could animate the transition, but that could be hard.

Comment: I updated my question to something more specific, because you don't really understand what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `display` instead of `opacity`.

But you should also set `div` to `display: block;` in `div.active` as below:

```
.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div.active, .tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div.active div {
  display: block; /* show it */
}
```

**Pay attention that if you want to set `div` into `div.active` with a different `display`than you need to add `!important` to make sure that it will be taken correctly.**

You also need to change some js in your for loop as below:

```
/** IF to point to the right div **/
    if(tabsPane[i].className.match(/\bstat\b/)){
      document.getElementById("stat").classList.add('active');
      document.getElementById("userManagement").classList.remove('active');
    }else if(tabsPane[i].className.match(/\buserManagement\b/)){
       document.getElementById("userManagement").classList.add('active');
      document.getElementById("stat").classList.remove('active');
    }
```

And to make it works I was adding classes and id such as `stat` and `userManagement` because it was not identifying correctly the div anymore.

### DEMO (Simple example):

```js
let tabHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-header")[0];
let tabIndicator = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-indicator")[0];
let tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-content")[0];

let tabsPane = tabHeader.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (let i = 0; i < tabsPane.length; i++) {
  tabsPane[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    tabHeader.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabsPane[i].classList.add("active");
    /*tabContent.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabContent.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.add("active");*/
    
    /** IF to point to the right div **/
    if(tabsPane[i].className.match(/\bstat\b/)){
      document.getElementById("stat").classList.add('active');
      document.getElementById("userManagement").classList.remove('active');
    }else if(tabsPane[i].className.match(/\buserManagement\b/)){
       document.getElementById("userManagement").classList.add('active');
      document.getElementById("stat").classList.remove('active');
    }


    tabIndicator.style.left = `calc(calc(100% / 2) * ${i})`;
  });
}
```

```css
/*--------------General----------------*/

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*-------------------------------------*/


/*-------------TabbedPage---------------*/

.tabbedpage {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div {
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div>i {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div.active {
  color: #d81e05;
  display: block;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-indicator {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: 5px;
  background: #d81e05;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none; /* hide it */
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0ms, transform 500ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div.active, .tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div.active div {
  display: block; /* show it */
}


/*--------------------------------------*/


/*---------------Footer-----------------*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
}

footer .red-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #d81e05;
  height: 120px;
}

footer .red-bar .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}


/*------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabbedpage">
    <div class="tabbedpage-header">
      <div class="stat active">
        statistics
      </div>
      <div class="userManagement">
        user management
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabbedpage-indicator"></div>
    <div class="tabbedpage-content">
      <div id="stat" class="active">
        <h2>This is statistics section</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error neque saepe commodi blanditiis fugiat nisi aliquam ratione porro quibusdam in, eveniet accusantium cumque. Dolore officia reprehenderit perferendis quod libero omnis.</p>
        <div>DIV IN DIV 2</div>
      </div>
      <div id="userManagement">
        <h2>This is the user management section</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi minus exercitationem vero, id autem fugit assumenda a molestiae numquam at, quisquam cumque. Labore eligendi perspiciatis quia incidunt quaerat ut ducimus?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="red-bar">
    <div class="container content">
      <p> Bel nu ons contact center <br> <b>023 751 06 06</b> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

### DEMO (Large example):

```js
let tabHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-header")[0];
let tabIndicator = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-indicator")[0];
let tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-content")[0];

let tabsPane = tabHeader.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (let i = 0; i < tabsPane.length; i++) {
  tabsPane[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    tabHeader.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabsPane[i].classList.add("active");
    /*tabContent.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabContent.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.add("active");*/
    
    /** IF to point to the right div **/
    if(tabsPane[i].className.match(/\bstat\b/)){
      document.getElementById("stat").classList.add('active');
      document.getElementById("userManagement").classList.remove('active');
    }else if(tabsPane[i].className.match(/\buserManagement\b/)){
       document.getElementById("userManagement").classList.add('active');
      document.getElementById("stat").classList.remove('active');
    }


    tabIndicator.style.left = `calc(calc(100% / 2) * ${i})`;
  });
}
```

```css
/*--------------General----------------*/

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*-------------------------------------*/


/*-------------TabbedPage---------------*/

.tabbedpage {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div {
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div>i {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div.active {
  color: #d81e05;
  display: block;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-indicator {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: 5px;
  background: #d81e05;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none; /* hide it */
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0ms, transform 500ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div.active, .tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div.active div {
  display: block; /* show it */
}


/*--------------------------------------*/

/*-------------Statistics---------------*/

.activity-24h-title {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.activity-24h {
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    display: flex !important;     /** Add !important **/
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.activity-24h .stat-frame {
    position: relative;
    width:calc(100% / 5 - (4 * 2px));
    display: flex !important;    /** Add !important **/
    flex-direction: column
}

.activity-24h .stat-frame-title {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.activity-24h .stat-frame-value {
    color: #d81e05;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.activity-24h .seperation-border {
    width: 2px;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
}

/*--------------------------------------*/
/*---------------Footer-----------------*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
}

footer .red-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #d81e05;
  height: 120px;
}

footer .red-bar .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbedpage">
    <div class="tabbedpage-header">
        <div class="stat active">
            Statistieken
        </div>
        <div class="userManagement">
            Gebruikersbeheer
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabbedpage-indicator"></div>
    <div class="tabbedpage-content">
        <div id="stat" class="active">          
            <span class="activity-24h-title">Afgelopen 24 uur</span>
            <div class="activity-24h">
                <div class="stat-frame">
                    <span class="stat-frame-title">Nieuwe gebruikers</span>
                    <span class="stat-frame-value">513</span>
                </div>
                <div class="seperation-border"></div>
                <div class="stat-frame">
                    <span class="stat-frame-title">Actieve gebruikers</span>
                    <span class="stat-frame-value">1054</span>
                </div>
                <div class="seperation-border"></div>
                <div class="stat-frame">
                    <span class="stat-frame-title">Matches</span>
                    <span class="stat-frame-value">1577</span>
                </div>
                <div class="seperation-border"></div>
                <div class="stat-frame">
                    <span class="stat-frame-title">Gerapporteerd</span>
                    <span class="stat-frame-value">33</span>
                </div>
                <div class="seperation-border"></div>
                <div class="stat-frame">
                    <span class="stat-frame-title">Geblokkeerd</span>
                    <span class="stat-frame-value">9</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="userManagement">
            <h2>This is about section</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi minus exercitationem vero, id autem fugit assumenda a molestiae numquam at, quisquam cumque. Labore eligendi perspiciatis quia incidunt quaerat ut ducimus?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="red-bar">
    <div class="container content">
      <p> Bel nu ons contact center <br> <b>023 751 06 06</b> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: In my code I use multiple divs next to eachother, now the divs are all below eachother!? See my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vreesie/6v5cr0xy/1/

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk corrected and edit answer. It is because some `div` into the `div.active` have property `display: flex;` and not `block`. I add `!important` and in classes that where like this and it fixed it. You should set that if your div are in active with different display than `block`. As the following classes: `.activity-24h, .activity-24h .stat-frame { display: flex !important; }`

Comment: Great !  If you are facing any problem with this subject do not hesitate to  ask. Have a good day

Comment: After moralizing me you write the same answer as me except with the addition of the change of scope (which is not even present in the question) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using `display: none` and `display: block` instead of `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 1` to hide the inactive element:

```js
let tabHeader = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-header")[0];
let tabIndicator = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-indicator")[0];
let tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbedpage-content")[0];

let tabsPane = tabHeader.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (let i = 0; i < tabsPane.length; i++) {
  tabsPane[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    tabHeader.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabsPane[i].classList.add("active");
    tabContent.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].classList.remove("active");
    tabContent.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].classList.add("active");

    tabIndicator.style.left = `calc(calc(100% / 2) * ${i})`;
  });
}
```

```css
/*--------------General----------------*/

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/*-------------------------------------*/


/*-------------TabbedPage---------------*/

.tabbedpage {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div {
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  text-align: center;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div>i {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-header>div.active {
  color: #d81e05;
  display: block;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-indicator {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: 5px;
  background: #d81e05;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none; /* hide it */
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out 0ms, transform 500ms ease-in-out 0ms;
}

.tabbedpage .tabbedpage-content>div.active {
  display: block; /* show it */
}


/*--------------------------------------*/


/*---------------Footer-----------------*/

footer {
  width: 100%;
}

footer .red-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #d81e05;
  height: 120px;
}

footer .red-bar .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}


/*------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabbedpage">
    <div class="tabbedpage-header">
      <div class="active">
        statistics
      </div>
      <div>
        user management
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabbedpage-indicator"></div>
    <div class="tabbedpage-content">
      <div class="active">
        <h2>This is statistics section</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error neque saepe commodi blanditiis fugiat nisi aliquam ratione porro quibusdam in, eveniet accusantium cumque. Dolore officia reprehenderit perferendis quod libero omnis.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>This is the user management section</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi minus exercitationem vero, id autem fugit assumenda a molestiae numquam at, quisquam cumque. Labore eligendi perspiciatis quia incidunt quaerat ut ducimus?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="red-bar">
    <div class="container content">
      <p> Bel nu ons contact center <br> <b>023 751 06 06</b> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I still have 1 problem. If I put a `<div>` in the `<div class="active">`, the content of the second tab doesn't get shown anymore? Do you know why that is?

Comment: Could you provide me a jsfiddle for that ? I will answer it ;) but since the original answer solve your issue could validate and upvote it ? :)

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vreesie/6v5cr0xy/1/. As you can see, the Lorem Ipsum of the second tab doesn't get shown? You know why?

Comment: @johannchopin you cannot decide if the question has to be validated just because your answer fix a problem and actualy created another one... planty of time I saw you written: `validate and upvote ` and that is not welcome. Specialy on bounties

Comment: @MaxiGui Sorry man but the problem doesn't come from the css implementation but from the js script where the `.active` class is no reset on the right `div`. Moreover a question is ask, I solve it for this scenario, change of scope in a question is also not really welcome. You will see that at some point you will answer questions without receiving any answer (especially among users with low reputation). So a little reminder doesn't hurt.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk See MaxiGui's answer for you change of scope. But please add it at least to your question, so other user can understand why this answer isn't the right one.

Comment: @johannchopin I answer to the full expectation. Btw, yesterday, you "stole" kind of same answer that I was putting 5min prior in comments and then answering after the guy comment back: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375491/how-do-i-make-the-navbar-responsive-depending-on-the-viewport), so don't be mad and let it go with your reminders... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.write() to edit the document so you can remove add the div when required. Example:

```js
function runcode(){
  document.write("<div> hi </div>")
}
```

```css
#button{
background-color: red;
padding: 15px 32px;
}
#button:hover{
background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="runcode()" id="button">replace with a div with hi inside</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `display` instead of `opacity`, just as @MaxiGui wrote. You can be a bit fancy too, and create a tag for it:

```
invisible {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As a quick workaround you can modify `footer` style as following.

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```