# How do I make the navbar responsive depending on the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I want to make a responsive webpage. I want it to display a different nav based on the viewport. Here is the javascript that I have so far:

```js
var shownav = document.getElementById('show-nav');

if (screen.width < "720"){
  shownav.style.display = 'block';
}
```

But for some reason, it does not work. Can you please help me?

Comment: why dont you use css only ? with media query ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with media query. Can you show me how?

Comment: Try this [W3S - HTML Responsive Web Design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) and this [Responsive Web Design - Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this without javascript by using a [media-query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp):

```css
#show-nav {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}

/* if screen width is smaller than 720px, #show-nav will be a block */
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  #show-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="show-nav">
  Navbar
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you I understand now.

Comment: @LandonSooHoo No problem ;) Please `validate`  and `upvote` the answer if it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use only css to do so.

### DEMO (make it full page)

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
nav{
  width: 100vw;
  background:yellow;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px){
  nav{
    background:red;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Welcome</li>
  </ul>
</nav
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  #show-nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
```